# NetSuite Custom Field Search Failure

Tags: mule, netsuite, mule-component

I am running into an error using MuleSoft NetSuite Connector. I am searching on a custom field which performs correctly in the Sandbox Environment, but in the Production instance of NetSuite I am receiving the following error.

What could I possibly be missing that would cause this search to work properly in the Sandbox but not in Production? I have checked the roles, field names, etc. Is there some type of permission that enables custom field searching via API usage? The User is an Administrator.

**ERROR**

```
WARN  2017-04-24 15:08:21,209 [[sfdc-netsuite-integration].sfdcAccountToNSCustomerCreate.stage1.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {urn:platform_2016_2.webservices.netsuite.com}NetSuitePortTypeService#{urn:platform_2016_2.webservices.netsuite.com}search has thrown exception, unwinding now
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title>Error</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/ui/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/ui/jquery/jquery_isolation.js?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUtil.jsp?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUtil.js?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUIWidgets.jsp?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/legacy_widgets/1701411811.js?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/legacy_apputil/1733410633.js?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLAppUtil.jsp?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1&JSP_VER=1'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/uirefresh/script/global.js__NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63.nlqs?NS_VER=2017.1.0&minver=63'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/core/styles/pagestyles.nl?ct=-2&bglt=F2F4F6&bgmd=EDF1F7&bgdk=737A82&bgon=5C7499&bgoff=AFB5BF&bgbar=5C7499&tasktitletext=E4EAF4&crumbtext=E4EAF4&headertext=E4EAF4&ontab=FFFFFF&offtab=000000&text=000000&link=000000&bgbody=FFFFFF&bghead=FFFFFF&portlet=C0CAD9&portletlabel=000000&bgbutton=FFE599&bgrequiredfld=FFFFE5&font=Verdana%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif&size_site_content=9pt&size_site_title=9pt&size=1.0&nlinputstyles=T&accessibility=F&NS_VER=2017.1.0'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/uirefresh/css/button.css' />
    </head>

    <body bgcolor='#FFFFFF' link='#000000' vlink='#000000' alink='#330099' text='#000000' topmargin='0' marginheight='1' onload='page_init()' class='error-page'>
    <img src='/images/nav/stretch.gif' width='20'><a href='http://www.netsuite.com/portal/home.shtml'><img class='uir-logo' src='/images/logos/netsuite-reskin.png' height='30' border=0 style='margin-right:30px;'></a>
    <table border=0 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 width=100%>

    <tr><td class='bglt'>
    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='100%'>
    <tr><td class='textboldnolink'>Error</td></tr>
    <tr><td vAlign='top'>
    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
    <tr><td class='text'>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr><td class=text><img src='/images/5square.gif' width=5 height=5>An unexpected error has occurred. Please go back and try again.</td></tr>

    <tr><td class='text'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='text'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table></td></tr></table></td></tr>
    <tr><td class='text'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>

    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
    function page_init() {
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**BUILDING THE SEARCH**

```
public class SearchNSCustomerBySFDCAccountId extends AbstractMessageTransformer  {

    private final String FLOW_VAR_SFDCACCOUNT = "SFDCAccount";
    private final String SFDCACCOUNT_ID = "Id";
    private final String SFDC_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD = "custentitysfdc_account_id";

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        //Retrieve FlowVar - SFDCAccount
        HashMap<String, String> sfdcAcct = (HashMap<String, String>) message.getInvocationProperty(FLOW_VAR_SFDCACCOUNT);
        if(sfdcAcct == null) return null;

        String sfdcAcctId = sfdcAcct.get(SFDCACCOUNT_ID);
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(sfdcAcctId)) return null;

        //Building CustomField Search - SFDC Account Id
        CustomerSearchBasic custBasicSearch = new CustomerSearchBasic();
        SearchCustomFieldList searchCustomFieldList = new SearchCustomFieldList();
        List<SearchCustomField> listOfCustomFields = new ArrayList<SearchCustomField>();

        SearchStringCustomField sfdcAcctIdCustomField = new SearchStringCustomField();
        sfdcAcctIdCustomField.setOperator(SearchStringFieldOperator.IS);
        sfdcAcctIdCustomField.setScriptId(SFDC_ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD);
        sfdcAcctIdCustomField.setSearchValue(sfdcAcctId);

        listOfCustomFields.add(sfdcAcctIdCustomField);
        searchCustomFieldList.setCustomField(listOfCustomFields);
        custBasicSearch.setCustomFieldList(searchCustomFieldList);

        return custBasicSearch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the endpoint URL that you are using to configure the NetSuite API in Production?

If it is https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2016_1, can you try by https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2016_1 ?

Comment: I am using https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2016_2, I notice that there is a new 2017.1 release as well.

Comment: Use the Production credentials to get the dataCenterURL. Make sure you are not passing the endpoint URL in the API, leave it blank.

Comment: I am able to perform many different operations against the production environment using the above URL. I do not understand why it does not let me perform this search on a custom field though. Could it be anything else? I will try that. I believe it defaults to the URL I listed above though.

Comment: I have faced the exact same situation a couple of weeks back. Same operation in the same flow used to work for one custom record, but failed for another. Once I got the datacenterURL for that particular account ID, all interfaces started working as expected.